# Firefox can't find the file at sip: xxxx

Tags: firefox, voip, regedit, sip

Hi have a voip service that works great and use Bria Counterpath softphone - also good.  I have installed a click to call add on for Firefox and keep getting this error:

Firefox can't find the file at sip:

Any help much appreciated

Comment: That's very odd because Firefox should either (1) offer to launch an application or do something special if it understands the `sip:` URI scheme, or (2) give the error message "The address wasn't understood" if it doesn't have knowledge of the `sip:` URI scheme. Under no circumstances should it try to treat the URI as a file! What is the exact value of the hyperlink you are clicking on to get this error, and how is it generated (is it in an HTML page?)?

Comment: Is the sip protocol listed and associated with anything under Firefox Options / Applications tab, and [in Windows](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/9154-default-programs-associate-file-type-protocol.html) (be sure to scroll to the bottom of the associations window)?

Comment: hi  thanks for the heads up on checking the protocol.  This was set in firefox to another program.  Have change to the soft phone I have and will try again now!

Comment: Thanks Karen - changing the setting here worked... I did need to restart both firefox and the softphone, but all good now.!

Comment: additional note for others - this was NOT a regedit problem after-all, even though most searcg results wanted me to change settings in there!   Now just to get the buzz off the phone line!  lol

Answer (score 0):

1) Launch Firefox
2) Type about:config in the address bar and press ‘Enter’
3) Accept the warning
4) Right click somewhere on the page and select New –> Boolean from the menu
5) Set the name to “network.protocol-handler.expose.sip” without the quotes
6) Set the value to “false”
7) Close the about:config window (or tab)

http://blog.n3tg33kz.com/2010/12/adding-sip-uri-handling-to-firefox/

Comment: Link is broken.